# How to add class to its parent div when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick

I am using this script in Wordpress hence the $=jQuery.

This currently adds .current class to all .col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb divs.

How do I change this to only add the class to its parent's div?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".feature_thumb a").click(function(){

    jQuery(".col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb").addClass("current");

});

});
```

Can someone help me with this?

This is my html

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 feature_thumb">
    <a class="feature_thumb" id="feature_thumb1" onclick="return false;"  
    href="image1.jpg"><p>Image 1</p></a>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 feature_thumb">
    <a class="feature_thumb" id="feature_thumb12" onclick="return false;" 
    href="image2.jpg"><p>Image 2</p></a>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target` to get a reference to what was clicked and then find the closest DOM node that matches your selector like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".feature_thumb a").click(function(event) {
    jQuery(event.target).closest(".col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb").addClass("current");
  });

});
```

You likely need to remove the `current` classes from all the other nodes though so you probably want this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".feature_thumb a").click(function(event) {
    jQuery(".col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb.current").removeClass("current");
    jQuery(event.target).closest(".col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb").addClass("current");
  });

});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code. It works perfect but when you click the link, it adds the new class but, when you click again its not removing the class. can you help?

Comment: @OğuzKağanYatağan You could have a variable going to the thing clicked on -- so say `const myTarget = $(event.target).closest(".col-xs-4.col-sm-4.feature_thumb")` and then do an `if -- else --` with something like `if (myTarget.hasClass("current")) { ...removeClass("current"); } else { ...addClass("current"); }`. If you're using jQuery, it actually has a `toggleClass` to do this which would make it even simpler -- see https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/